# How many ways to build a perfectly balanced tree?

Tags: python, memory, tree, binary-tree, permutation

The question is, how many ways are there to build a perfectly balanced binary tree with 15 elements?

One possibility would bei 8-4-12-2-6-10-14-1-3-5-7-9-11-13-15..

My idea was to write some code that generates every possible permutation (which would be like.. 15!) and then remove the ones that are incorrect.

Correct ones have the 8 as the first element, 4 always comes before 2 and 6, 2 always comes before 1 and 3, 6 always comes before 5 and 7 and so on.

But something like `perms2 = list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]))` causes a memory error.

Is there a way to generate permutations with the rules as above?

Or is there even a more simple way to solve my problem?

Btw..

- if the amount of elements is 1, there is 1 way
- with 3 elements there are 2 ways (2-1-3 or 2-3-1)
- with 7 elements there are 80 ways (according to my code and doing it manually)

but that didn't help me to get some kind of formula..

Edit: this is the tree i am talking about: http://666kb.com/i/bz9znnpdj7etw0fo9.gif

Comment: 15! is quite a lot, no wonder you get errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct number is 21964800. This is the appropriate integer sequence:

http://oeis.org/A076615

Basically you recursively multiply the possibilities:
On the lowest level you can choose between two possibilities, e.g: 2-1-3 and 2-3-1. On the level above that you can entangle the chosen order of both lower layers in (6 over 3)
 ways and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by perfectly balanced. But if you mean both **number of left and right nodes are equal for every node** and you have 15 elements [1-15] which 2^4 -1 elements you can have a such a tree. Because a complete binary tree of four levels exactly has 15 elements.

Also from your question it seems like you mean a complete binary search tree.  With 15 elements ( 1-15) there is only one such tree possible.

Consider what can go in the root node. What number is the exact median of 1-15. It is 8 and 8 only. so only 8 can be at the root. And if you use induction you will conclude that all nodes only have one possible value

Comment: I would say that balanced can be understood in the sense that each node is accessible by a path of the same or +1 length from the root, which would make a few more, but not so much

Comment: yeah sure, but there are several ways to add elements.. after you set the 8 as root node, you can either add 4 or 12.. and if you decide to add 4 as left child, you can now choose between adding 12 as right child of 8 or adding either 2 or 6 as children of 4.. and so on

Comment: If you want the tee to `perfect` in the that sense each node has the property that leftchildcount is same as rightchildcount only one such tree is possible. You can deduce this from induction

Comment: @Marc - the example sequence seems to imply an ordered binary search tree - it seems to be scanning the tree top-down and left-to-right, so the first item is the root. That suggests there's no choice where the items go, other than based on what leaves are present at the deepest level.

Comment: http://666kb.com/i/bz9znnpdj7etw0fo9.gif

this is the tree.. but you can have different orders of adding elements to that tree

Comment: The ways of building such a tree are as many as there are ways to skin a cat

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a formula to be found. See with a small tree how many posibilities there are.

For example, for 3 different elements, there is only 1 possible tree.

For 4, there are 2

For 5, there are 3

For 6, there are only 2 (3 and 4 as root, the rest is implied)

For 7, only 1.

For 15, given a root, there are 14 elements to place, which happens to be 7+7, which is representable in only one form, so my guess as to your problem is that there is only one solution, and 8 is root.

Comment: sry.. this is the tree i am talking about
http://666kb.com/i/bz9znnpdj7etw0fo9.gif

but there is not only one way to add elements to that tree

Comment: this is the only balanced representation of the tree, because it is full (all leaves are at the same depth)

Comment: i know.. but there are thousands of ways to build such a tree.. and i want to know how much exactly

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have 15 elements, there is only one possible balanced tree.

Comment: but not only one way to create that tree

Comment: you mean, like insert orders ? that would trivially be 2^7

Comment: as I said, there are 80 ways to construct a perfectly balanced binary search tree with 7 elements. the full list can be seen here
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20843750/permutationen.txt

Comment: referring to your permutationen.txt, how are those balanced binary trees? For instance, 1: (4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7), is not a binary tree since the left subtree under 4 is (2, 3, 6): all values should be lower than 4. The values in the right subtree (1, 5, 7) should all be larger than 4, but aren't either.

Comment: exactly! And if it is not a sorted tree, why is 4 the root?

Comment: @njzk2: Now that you mention it, I think you're interpretation is correct: parent node inbetween child nodes. In that case putting 2 as root would yield unballanced subtrees, since one subtree is only (1). Still, the question is very unclear

Comment: These are not all balanced binary trees.. these are ways to add values to that tree. 4,2,1,3,6,5,7 means that you first add 4 to that tree, then 2 (which will be the left child) then 1 (which will be the left child of 2) then 3 (which will be the right child of 2) then 6 (which will be the right child of 4) and so on.. this does NOT mean that this is some kind of array and the index of a value is NOT the index of that value in a tree or array!

Comment: Aaah, so your additional algorithmic rules (which you didn't state): 1) you can only add *leaf* nodes at each insertion, 2) nodes must be added in the provided order, and 3) the tree cannot be restructured during creation.

Comment: Does that help you in any way?

My mathematical problem may be: How many permutations of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) are there with 1) 4 as first element 2) 2 has a lower index than 1 or 3 and 3) 6 has a lower index than 5 or 7?

Comment: If your tree is supposed to be as catchmeifyoutry stated and must be balanced and binary, then, there are 3 nodes with children, hence 2^3 combinations for insert order, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

With your definition of perfectly balanced, all the variation in structure happens at the deepest level of the tree, so you only need to worry about that one level.

A maximal balanced tree with height h will have 2^(h-1) leaves - e.g. for height 1, the only leaf is the root. These are all at the deepest level.

A minimal balanced tree with height h has only one node at the deepest level.

The number of ways you can construct a perfectly balanced binary tree is therefore the same as the number of ways you can have between 1 and 2^(h-1) nodes at the deepest level.

There are 2^(h-1) nodes that may or may not be present at that level (a combinations problem, not permutations), so you get 2^(2^(h-1)) possiblilities, of which only one (the "none" case) is invalid.

So I think your answer is (2^(2^(h-1)))-1. So if you can determine the correct h...

That's assuming a binary *search* tree (with item values unique and in order), so the binary tree is fully determined by the choice of which deepest-level nodes are present. Otherwise, you multiply that by the number of permutations of the sequence of values.

Take care with my definition of h - a zero-height tree would have no nodes at all, and give a nonsense result - sqrt(2)-1 is an irrational answer in at least two senses.

**EDIT**

Marcs comment made me think some more. For a particular height I think my answer is right. The problem is that a particular height allows various different numbers of total nodes, because it allows various different numbers of nodes in that deepest layer. So I can't get the correct answer for one particular node count this way. So... lets try again...

If our tree has height h, it can have at most (2^h)-1 nodes in total. Excluding the deepest level, it has (2^(h-1))-1 nodes - all of which must be present.

We have c-((2^(h-1))-1) nodes at the deepest level, and we get to choose where to put those nodes from the 2^(h-1) possible positions at the deepest level. I use c for count, because I want to define...

```
n = 2^(h-1)
k = c-((2^(h-1))-1)
```

answer = [n choose k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

I still haven't derived h from c - it should be the floor of the base 2 logarithm, but I have that out-by-one-somewhere feeling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i tried that formula and it does not work :(

The structure is not variable.. only the order of input.
First input must be 8.
Second input can bei 4 or 12.
Third input can be 4 or 12 or 2 or 6 or 10 or 14, depending on what you chose before.

Comment: @Marc - given that only "perfectly" balanced trees are valid, and if the tree is a binary search tree, the order of inputs is only relevant to the degree that the structure can vary. In a comment somewhere, you said not all leaves were at the deepest level - some can be at the next level up. That's the same variation of structure I'm describing above - the minimum variation of structure that allows for e.g. a tree of size 14. Each variation I allow for can arise (and will arise) by varying the insertion order.

Comment: @Marc - some arrangements of the tree may be generated by more than one ordering of the insertions - if you're counting input orderings rather than resulting tree arrangements, that's the only way I can see my answer being wrong - but then again, I've already made at least one daft mistake ;-)